# Unable to load images in device using device image URL?

Tags: objective-c, image, ios9, photosframework

i have list of selected images from photos gallery. After that i am retrieving all that images URL by this way.

```
  PHImageManager *manager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];
 [manager requestImageForAsset:asset
                           targetSize:PHImageManagerMaximumSize
                          contentMode:PHImageContentModeDefault
                              options:self.requestOptions
                        resultHandler:^void(UIImage *image, NSDictionary *info) {

                            NSLog(@"%@",[info valueForKey:@"PHImageFileURLKey"]);
                            NSURL *imageURL = (NSURL *)[info valueForKey:@"PHImageFileURLKey"];
                            NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
                            UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];                                  
                        }];
```

Now the problem is it perfectly load images in simulator but when i run in device it unable to load images.i got null NSData.
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Does Albumimages contain NSURLs or NSStrings?

Comment: it contain NSURLs.

Comment: Can you add the code where you create and add the URLs to the collection?

Comment: check i add the code where i add fetch URL of asset .

Comment: Are you sure your Albumimages collection is correctly instantiated etc? try printing out imageURL when you retrieve it from the collection

Comment: are you fetch photo gallery image right?

Comment: Yes kb920. can u suggest me how can i handle with this problem with minimum memory use because i have multiple large size images.

Comment: i am fetching images from photo gallery and store those images in application document directory.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try

```
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imageURL];
```

as opposed to

```
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
```

Comment: i dont get the issue becuase its working well in the simulator but when i run in device i got null image data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following line is creating a problem.

```
NSURL *imageURL = [Albumimages objectAtIndex:i];
```

First check here if you are getting the exact URL you are looking for, by copy it and run it on the mac browser. If not, then you need to create a `NSURL` in a following way

```
NSString* stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSString* webStringURL = [stringURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL];
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: Yes i get correct URL. And also check it on browser. But now the problem is its correctly working in simulator but if i run it in device i got null data.